# What is the difference between strcmpi and stricmp functions?

Tags: c, string

I was searching for the exact difference in strcmpi and stricmp.Both are used to ignore case.
And i also found in 'let us c' that,**stricmp** compares string without regard to case(identical to strcmpi).
unable in understanding the proper meaning of above defination of stricmp.
**strcmpi**:-this simply ignores the case.
I surfed internet but didn't found answer.

Comment: Just poor standardization.  Everybody needs it, the C standard won't give it.   So C library writers provide it anyway, that they can't agree about the name is the inevitable outcome.  That you can't get it has a very good reason, casing is a complete mine-field in modern location-aware code.

Comment: The ANSI version is named `strcasecmp()`

Comment: @wildplasser strcasecmp is in POSIX, but not in ISO C even today.

Comment: The _stricmp function ordinally compares string1 and string2 after converting each character to lowercase, and returns a value indicating their relationship.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmpi` and `stricmp` are case-insensitive versions of `strcmp`. They work identically in all other respects.

The method `strcmpi` is the same as `stricmp`. `strcmpi` is implemented through a
macro in string.h and translates calls from `stricmp` to stricmp.

A few differences between `strcmpi()` and `stricmp()`:

1. `strcmpi` macro is provided for compatibility with other C compilers.
2. portability:

   - `strcmpi` dos, unix and win32 and ansi C++
   - `stricmp` dos, unix, win16, win32 and os/2

Notice that those two methods are not Standard C, and unless absolutely necessary, it's advised to avoid them.

References:

1. [Difference between strcmpi() and stricmp()?](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.c/c/MrN1uxipcGY?pli=1)
2. [strcmp, strcmpi, stricmp, wcscmp, _wcsicmp](http://support.tenasys.com/INtimeHelp_62/strcmp.html#:%7E:text=strcmpi%20and%20stricmp%20are%20case,names%20for%20strcmpi%20and%20stricmp.&text=wcscmp%20and%20_wcsicmp%20are%20wide,of%20strcmp%20and%20stricmp%20respectively.)

Comment: How can you say that these functions are part of ANSI C and C++, and then say that they aren't standard?

Comment: @interjay good catch, it was a miss, fixed! :)